# How to migrate CXF from 2.7 to 3.0?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, tomcat, cxf

I used CXF with version 2.7.11. I changed the version on version 3.0.4. CXF is integrated to Spring framework application.

I have to fixed only one compilation error in my interceptor class.

`Conduit conduit = exchange.getDestination().getBackChannel(inMessage, null, target);` was changed on `Conduit conduit = exchange.getDestination().getBackChannel(inMessage);`

I deployed it on Tomcat but it fails on this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'activity': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REFLECTION
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1763)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:856)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:805)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:856)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:805)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1476)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:98)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1317)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1409)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:839)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:564)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:825)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:616)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:678)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REFLECTION
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:464)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:310)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:534)
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.jaxb.proxy.JaxbContextFactory.buildContext(JaxbContextFactory.java:31)
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.jaxb.proxy.JaxbContextProxyHandler.buildContext(JaxbContextProxyHandler.java:133)
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.jaxb.proxy.JaxbContextProxyHandler.<init>(JaxbContextProxyHandler.java:103)
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.jaxb.proxy.JaxbContextProxy.createProxy(JaxbContextProxy.java:68)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1169)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:222)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:383)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:594)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:347)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:345)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.createContext(JAXBContextCache.java:345)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:246)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createJAXBContextAndSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:479)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:334)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:467)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:712)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:261)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:215)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:456)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:334)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:539)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    ... 59 more
```

Here is my CXF context file, it is imported to spring context file.

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
       xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>

    <bean id="ActivityWebService" class="com.example.activity.ActivityWebService"/>
    <jaxws:endpoint id="activity" implementor="#ActivityWebService" address="/Activity"/>

    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="basicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor"/>
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
    </cxf:bus>

    <bean id="basicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor" class="com.example.api.BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor"/>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be "a duplicate" of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5894:
Please check your class path for conflicting `jaxb-` libraries!

Comment: Thanks for link to issue. Help me disable execution of `flatten-maven-plugin`.